# Different browser behaviour when positioning svgs

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to center svgs on top of each other. I am using the same method to position the divs and the svgs inside each other, but this is only working in chrome.

Following code is used to center:

```
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

[image: Chrome svg position]

This is how it looks like in Firefox:

[image: Firefox svg position]

The code can be found [here.](http://codepen.io/wederer/pen/EyVGrK?editors=1100)

Does anybody have a clue?

EDIT: I have found out what is happening: Firefox is applying the transform to the svg itself and thus moving the svg out of the viewbox. Have not found a solution yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have now found the answer:

Firefox cascaded the translation onto the "use" tag and thus the position of the svg on the viewbox got translated. To counteract this i added the css rule:

```
use{
  transform: translate(50% 50%)
}
```

Feel free to add any insight as to why this is happening.

Comment: Per the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) if you point a use at a symbol you get the contents of the symbol cloned **within a generated svg element**

Comment: @RobertLongson Do you know why chrome does not follow the specification?

Comment: No, I'm a Firefox developer!